# how to design mvc entity models

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Its always a pain for me to design models. The way iam progressing is:

1. find out the data involved
2. create database with data
3. create entity models with data manually ie without table2class conversion

The reason i told without table2class conversion is: i really need to understand how to do it on mysql/manually. I am a beginner and i really feel hard each time i put hand on this area.

Consider an example of saving Rating for employee and company. employee can rate self and several employees can rate a company. So the database become:

1. employeerating   :   id | employee_id | tag_id | rating
2. companyrating    :   id | company_id | employee_id | tag_id | rating

How we design models for this scenario. I really don't get it. Below is the model wanted.

```
[Table("employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Rating> ratings { get; set; }
}
[Table("company")]
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    ...
    List of List of Rating which can seperate by each employee
    what should come here 
}
```

how we design models to accomplish employee_rating and employee_company_rating. please point if iam entirely wrong.

also suggest some tutorial for me on how to do/think for model design

Answer (score 1):

That's a data-centric approach and there are plenty of resources out there for that. You might also want to consider a more object oriented approach that code first encourages. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264379/code-first-vs-database-first

As for your current issue, based on what you describe you want another class that bridges employees and companies:

```
public class CompanyEmployee
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Rating> CompanyRatings { get; set; }
}
```

You can add a list of employees to the company for navigation. Also, you don't need the Table annotations if the class and table name are the same.

Comment: like you said about removing annotation if table name are same. thus we can reduce some more code. i think that's the beauty of manually doing. but what need is to understand !

Comment: is this bridge class is to mimic our table "companyrating : id | company_id | employee_id | tag_id | rating". If so this is new to me. wondering how come multiple entries on db with entries on List-Rating

Comment: Yes, it depends on whether you want ratings as a 1:many like a lookup table or many-to-many. Here is some background http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx